# Reference an entire .NET class in Access 2013 with a DLL

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access, dll

So lately I have been building a DLL in C# for my Access 2013 Frontend application that handles mail through SMTP and does some validation since Access Mailing library's did not fulfill my requirements.

This all worked great but it also got me wondering, and I cant really find an answer to it on the forum hence my question, is it possible that instead of creating my own mailing methods and classes to just create one COM visible class and make it inherit from, in my example, the Mailing class (SMTPClient for example) so that in Access I can call the properties/methods from the inherited .NET class?

I actually don't think it is possible because then there would be likely more info on the subject but on the other hand, Access 2013 had a lot of improvements and one of them being importing DLL's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure really why not? The only issue is when you create your class (com) object, is the required code stubs placed into the class as public members so Access can see them?

The only real caution here is if you not building a custom interface in your class (I usually don’t), then any property exposed as a non-compatible VBA variable type will render the whole COM object as invalid. (so make those routines (and variables) as private).

So as a general rule, any method/property of your class that is exposed to Access will have to be a public property – this suggests and implies that you can inherit the original object properties into your custom class – but you still need public code stubs to expose those methods/properties.

I don’t use c#, but in vb.net, when you inherit, then all of the code stubs are auto-generated for you – so if c# is the same, then I don’t see why this approach will not work for you.